# Proof explanation, prop 7.16 "Introduction to Topological Manifold" by Lee

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have a question about the proof of proposition 7.16 in Lee's Topological Manifold text.  The proof is shown below.

[image]

My first question is that for the first paragraph when he shows a) implies b), the map $ \tilde{H} $ is a homotopy that fix the endpoint $p$ for all $t \in I$ , is that correct,  since $\tilde{H}( (1,0), t) = p $ for all $t \in I$ due to the fact that $f$ is a loop based at $p$?  So then $ \tilde{f}$ is not freely homotopic to a constant map then ??

My second question is about the part where he shows b) implies c).  I don't get the last sentence of that paragraph.  what does he mean by "because the quotient map restricts to the obvious identification $~~ \mathbb{S}^1 \times \{1\} \approx \mathbb{S}^1 \hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{B}}^2$ ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, we start with our map $H:\Bbb S^1\times I\to X$, and by definition of $H_0$ being a constant map, all of $\Bbb S^1\times\{0\}$ is sent to the same point and therefore we get an induced map $\tilde H:C\Bbb S^1\to X$, which is the same as a map $\tilde H:\bar{\Bbb{B}}^2\to X$.

Let $\pi:\Bbb S^1\times I\to (\Bbb S^1\times I)/(\Bbb S^1\times\{0\})=C\Bbb S^1\cong\bar{\Bbb{B}}^2$ be our quotient map. Do you have an image of what the latter homeomorphism looks like? Imagine the space $C\Bbb S^1$, which is just a cone:

[image]

The homeomorphism is obtained by "pushing everything down". When we do this, where does $\Bbb S^1\times\{1\}$ go? It just gets sent to the unit circle.

So when we restrict $\tilde H$ to $\Bbb S^1\times\{1\}$, we're really restricting it to the unit circle. But this restriction is also equal to the restriction of $H$ to $S^1\times\{1\}$, which by definition is $\tilde f$. Hence $\tilde H$ is a map $\bar{\Bbb{B}}^2\to X$ such that $\tilde H|_{\Bbb S^1}=\tilde f$, as desired.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was at work.  your answer is very clear, but I just want to ask when you say " $ \tilde{H}: C \mathbb{S}^1 \to X $ which is the same as a map $ \tilde{H}: \overline{ \mathbb{B}}^2 \to X $ ", do you mean that if $ \tilde{H}: C \mathbb{S}^1 \to X $ is the induce map from the quotient, and $\phi: C \mathbb{S}^1 \to \overline{ \mathbb{B}}^2 $ is the homeomorphism that you describe, then the map that we want is the composition $ \tilde{H} \circ \phi^{-1} : \overline{\mathbb{B}}^2 \to X $, is that what you mean by saying that they are the same map?

Comment: @Khoata Yes, precisely!